# Why is my hot water barely running in tub

Tags: water

I have both cold and hot water running in my house . The problem is the hot water barely trickles in bathtub . I have changed changed Faucet . Help Plz ! Tamatha

Comment: Did the problem occur before or after you changed the faucet.  Did you open all shutoff valves after replacing the faucet?

Comment: That would be my first suspicion as well. Is the hot waster pressure normal everywhere else?